# Why does Eclipse mark valid JavaScript with an error?

Tags: javascript, eclipse

The JavaScript:

```
[a,b] = [b,a];
```

The Eclipse error:

> The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable

Is there some plugin or something I need in order to get Eclipse to correctly inspect JavaScript?

Comment: That's not valid JavaScript 1.5 (what's used in browsers) so it's flagging it.

Comment: Destructuring assignment is not part of the current ECMAScript standard. Try running that in anything other than Firefox.

Comment: If you're interested, you can read the [Harmony proposal for it](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:destructuring).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's only valid in Mozilla's JavaScript implementation, found in Firefox for example.

Technically this is actual *"JavaScript"* according to a more technical definition of the word, but it's currently not valid *"ECMAScript"*, which is usually what people are talking about when they use the word *"JavaScript"*.